# Can session variables be retrieved in an iOS full screen web app?

Tags: php, ios, session, iphone-standalone-web-app

Im building an iOS web application.

On testing it from the home screen icon in full screen mode i was unable to get past the login screen despite it working perfectly in iPhone safari.

I worked out that this is due to a session variable not being available when it needs to be.

Very briefly... on page load the login form generates a hash number like a key, and is stored in a hidden field and it is also stored as a session variable.

When the form is processed, the hidden field containing the key is then checked against the session variable, as part of the validation (as a simple security measure), however the session variable is not available to the validation php script and so it throws an error.

I'm using the following code at the top of each page as ive read it helps maintain a session.

```
session_start();
$cookieLifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // A year in seconds
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$cookieLifetime);
```

Why might this session variable not be available?